# How to use pushViewController in interaction transition with panGestureRecoginizer

Tags: ios, transition, interactive

I try to implement a simple interaction transition which uses Pan Gesture. It looks like in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBEaKzM0dzE&feature=youtu.be).
I have sample project working with storyboard. The project is in this [link](https://github.com/tsunglintsai/InteractiveTransitionIssue).
 However, if I replace "performSegueWithIdentifier..."in line 50 of ViewController with "pushViewController:controller" which is commented out in line 51. the pan gesture just get canceled right away. What's the difference between call  "performSegueWithIdentifier" and "pushViewController:controller". they basically just push to another viewcontroller. Any suggest that I can make it working with pushViewController method call instead of calling performSegueWithIdentifier? any insight will be much appreciated.

```
switch (panGuesture.state)
{
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        NSLog(@"======================UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushNP" sender:panGuesture]; //line 50
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES]; //line 51
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        NSLog(@"======================UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged");
        float percentageOfPan = [self percentageOfPan:touchLocation];
        NSLog(@"=======percentageOfPan:%f",percentageOfPan);
        [self.transition updateInteractiveTransition:percentageOfPan];
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        NSLog(@"======================UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled");
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        NSLog(@"======================UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
        if(touchLocation.y < 600){
            [self.transition finishInteractiveTransition];
        } else {
            [self.transition cancelInteractiveTransition];
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two different methods are instantiating two different view controllers. The segue instantiates the instance of NPViewController that you have in the storyboard, whereas when you do the push, you're pushing a plain UIViewController that you alloc init'd.

The first few lines of your pan gesture recognizer's handler should look like this,

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)panGuesture{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [panGuesture locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"==========pan touch location:%f,%f",touchLocation.x,touchLocation.y);
    //UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    NPViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NPViewController"];
    controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    switch (panGuesture.state)
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            NSLog(@"======================UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan");
           // [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushNP" sender:panGuesture];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
            break;
```

I've commented out the line that you used to instantiate a UIViewController. Make sure that you add an identifier for your NPViewController in the storyboard.

Comment: Hi rdelmar, thank you for the reply. it does work when I change code based on your suggestion. but what if I want to create my own uiviewcontroller without using storyboard. Can't I create UIViewController just like what I had in project?

Comment: @TsungLinTsai, I'm not sure. I'm still trying to figure out why it doesn't work the way you originally wrote it. I would think that you should still get the percent driven transition, but just to a different view controller than the one you made in the storyboard.

Comment: @ rdelmar  thank you for looking into this. I have searched everything on stackoverflow and github about interactive transition, and I can't seem to find a working example for using pushViewController method. PopViewControllerAnimated seems work just fine somehow.

Comment: @TsungLinTsai, the problem is in your animationControllerForOperation... method where you have an if clause that only returns the animator if toVC is an NPViewController. Change that to   if ( ! [toVC isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]]), and it should work properly. This should make it work for any view controller class in the forward direction, but have no custom transition on the pop.

Comment: @ rdelmar. that resolves the issue. thank you very much. I have also created a resolved_issue branch on github to demo the code in case anyone encounter similar issue.